# What does "Break Wind" mean in context of location?

Tags: meaning

In *Mank (2020)*, Orson Welles speaks to Mank, who living near sun-bleached sewer:

> Orson Welles: If anyone should ask, tell 'em you're adapting.
>
> Mank: Oh, you don't know this sun-bleached sewer here, my friend.
> **Break wind** at Hollywood and Vine, and a producer in Santa Monica
> reports a ruptured main.

What does "Break Wind" mean in context of location?

Comment: To "break wind" is to ***fart***. I suppose "sun-bleached sewer" implies that the sewer isn't actually in use, so the idea is that just someone farting into the sewer would be sufficiently unusual that someone many miles away (but connected to the same sewer pipe) might think there was something wrong with the pipework. If this is some complex riff off of ["think one's shit doesn't stink"](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/think+your+shit+doesn%27t+stink#:~:text=for%20some%20readers.-,think%20(one's)%20shit%20doesn't%20stink,more%20refined%20than%20other%20people.), it's too subtle for me!

Comment: @Fumble I would imagine "sun-bleached sewer" refers to LA as a whole—a cesspool, but a sunny one.

Comment: Fart at that intersection of Hollywood and Vine (streets) and a producer will say some miles away (in Santa Monica) that a sewer main has broken. That is the meaning here. Sun-bleached sewer because that intersection "became known in the 1920s for its concentration of radio and movie-related businesses". Wikipedia. And the speaker is calling the people in those businesses sun-bleached shit.

Comment: @randomhead: Yeah, you're probably right. The basic idea is that the people in the area lead such a "rarefied" existence they wouldn't know how to deal with the harsh realities of real life (where people really do have to deal with bodily functions). Reminds me of an observation by some sci-fi writer (Asimov?, Zelazny?) to the effect that the level of "sophistication" for a civilisation can be measured by how quickly they can put how much distance between the excreter and his excrement! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Breaking wind" means exactly what any dictionary says it means—it is a term for *flatulence*. As you point out the relevant context is the distance.

*Hollywood Boulevard and Vine Street* is an intersection in Los Angeles. It is fifteen miles away from *Santa Monica*, on the coastline. Mank is saying that, because of the exaggeration and rumor mills prevalent in the LA area, a tiny thing (someone "breaking wind") can easily be turned into a story about a very large thing (an exploding natural gas line) by the time the story reaches the other side of town.

Comment: @Lambie: Wikipedia says `Flatulence is defined in the medical literature as "flatus expelled through the anus" or the "quality or state of being flatulent"`—the term can refer to the condition but also to the action.

Comment: @randomhead: "...to the action?" You use *flatulence* as a verb? "I had to flatulence"?

Comment: In closely connected communities, news travels fast. In the Isle of Wight, they say 'if someone sneezes in Ventnor, someone gets out a handkerchief in Shanklin"

Comment: @OldBrixtonian true, I wouldn't use it as a verb (and shouldn't have in the answer), but as a noun it can refer to *the act of* passing gas, despite Lambie's protestations.

Comment: @Lambie: it [break**ing** wind] is a term for the condition/action of hav**ing** flatulence. Compare freez**ing** being a term for the condition of be**ing** cold.

Comment: @Lambie: instead of saying "break wind" means "flatulence," I should have said "break wind" means "*have* flatulence." Happy?

Comment: I always thought, like @Lambie, that flatulence was a build up of gas in the digestive system, and breaking wind, passing wind, farting, etc, was releasing some of it, but I see that some people (including the UK NHS) use 'flatulence' for both.